# Is there a command to duplicate a map in Carto?

Tags: carto

I'm hoping to make a quick duplicate of a map in Carto, the same way you can 'make a copy' of a spreadsheet or a word doc.

My plan is to add a new map layer (with new data) to the duplicate and delete the old data to create a new map with all the same attributes as before, but new geography.

I can't modify the original because it's embedded in a live webpage.

Comment: You could click on a map description field (under the preview), then the new panel appears on top with `Duplicate map` option. Is it what you need or I misunderstood you?

Comment: Are you using the newer Builder software? I haven't migrated yet and maybe that's the issue. I've asked Carto to migrate me and I'll be in touch!

Comment: @JackJulian where did you ask for support? send us an email to `support@carto.com` and we'll be more than happy to upgrade you (I have no idea why but you should already be migrated!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can duplicate maps easily, there are two ways:

- If you are in the dashboard just select a map clicking in the card and you'll see a menu in the upper right side with the `Duplicate map` label.
- Inside the dashboard interface, click in the actions menu just right the dashboard name (the three vertical dots) and you'll see the `Duplicate` action with the `Rename`, `Delete` and so on.

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I've upgraded to Builder from Editor, and the command is right there. Thanks!